# I need unusual ordering mysql results

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to order results ASCENDING from the current date

this is what im using now;

```
SELECT * FROM friends JOIN bdays 
ON bdays.user = friends.friendname 
WHERE username = $userid ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%m %d')
```

any ideas?

**example**
ordering by date now, sorts the birthdays starting at january

what i need, is instead of starting the list at january, is starting it from the current date.

So, instead of;

```
January
February
March
April
May
June
July
August
September
November
December
```

It will order them like this;

```
April (current month/day)
May
June
July
August
September
November
December
January
February
March
April (all the way up to yesterday)
```

Comment: why do you format it? why not just ` ORDER BY date`?

Comment: the year isnt useful in my specific case, these are birthdays, so the year doesnt matter

Comment: well this should work. what is format of date field?

Comment: YYYY-MM-DD format, mysql datetime format

Comment: You don't say *how* it doesn't work.  Can you give an example of some rows that don't sort how you expect them to?  It would help if you show what the result of the query is, and how that is different from what you expected.

Comment: well what's wrong with the order you get? And why do you have separate bdays table?

Comment: it sorts the birthdays starting january, but i want them sorted asc from the current date

Comment: omg it being sorted ASC! and if you want it to be filtered, add a WHERE condition, don't think mysql will telepathically understand your *wishes*

Comment: i gathered that much...which is why i need help understanding how to accomplish this...sans the telepathy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
ORDER BY
   DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m %d') < DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),"%m %d"),
   DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m %d');
```

First, order by whether or not the date is less than the current date, then order by month and date in ascending order.

**NOTE**
This looks like the method Col. Shrapnel was referring to.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
SELECT *, (DATE_FORMAT(date, '%j')-DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%j')+365)%365 AS d 
FROM foo ORDER BY d;
```

The `%j` date format is the day of the year, i.e. a number 001...366.

I tested this on some sample data and it sorts in the way you describe: it ignores the year, and sorts the next date that falls after the current date first, then ascending, and wrapping around to dates earlier in the year.

```
+----+------------+------+
| id | date       | d    |
+----+------------+------+
|  5 | 1999-05-15 |   27 |
|  6 | 1992-06-15 |   59 |
|  7 | 1990-07-15 |   88 |
|  8 | 1988-08-15 |  120 |
|  9 | 1980-11-15 |  212 |
|  1 | 2010-01-15 |  272 |
|  2 | 2009-02-15 |  303 |
|  3 | 2004-03-15 |  332 |
|  4 | 2002-04-15 |  362 |
+----+------------+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

something like order by if(date_format(date,'%m%d') < date_format(now(),'%m%d')),1,0), date_format(date,'%m%d')

Answer (score 1):

you might try:

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%m %d') as adate FROM friends JOIN bdays 
ON bdays.user = friends.friendname 
WHERE username = $userid 
ORDER BY adate
```