# OrderBy clause sorting issue?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to order by `Date` in SQL Server I am facing a weird issue. There are 2 cases I should explain to help you understand my issue .

**Case 1 :**

```
select [MonthName] 
from prod.[dim date] 
where F_Year = 2014   
order by [Date]
```

My output:

```
june june june july july july july august  
// Here I get duplicates but order by is working as expected
```

**Case 2 :** tried to remove duplicates by using "distinct"

```
select distinct [MonthName] 
from prod.[dim date] 
where F_Year = 2014   
order by [Date]
```

My output:

```
August july june 
// Order By not working as expected (ordering alphabetical wise ) .
```

Any workaround is appreciated

Comment: What's the **datatype** of `date` in your table? Can you show us the table structure (columns and their datatypes) and your data that's stored in that table?

Comment: How does `SELECT DISTINCT [MonthName] ... ORDER BY [Date]` even work? SQL Server won't let you order by fields that don't appear in the `SELECT DISTINCT` clause.

Comment: Did you mean `order by [MonthName]` in the second statement?

Comment: Making some assumptions about your data... `SELECT [MonthName] ... GROUP BY MonthName ORDER BY MIN([Date])`

Comment: @MartinSmith: Seems an answer to me.

Comment: marc_s : format is Date only

Comment: show your table structure and sample data

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your query seems to be working off a table with 3 fields representing possibly a single date or maybe 2 - hard to tell without the structure but I can see : F_Year, [Date] & [MonthName].  So if these actually represent a single date, then revert to that single date and use formatting to determine F_Year and MonthName.

Secondly check out these posts for a probable answer to your question:

[Sort by Date in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195818/sort-by-date-in-sql?rq=1)

[Convert Month Number to Month Name Function in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185520/convert-month-number-to-month-name-function-in-sql)